# Wrong bluetooth device name

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth, headset

Did pair a bluetooth headset and below is the info..

```
[HD 350BT]# info
Device 00:1B:66:1D:19:FE (public)
    Name: LE-HD 350BT
    Alias: LE-HD 350BT
    Class: 0x00240418
    Icon: audio-card
    Paired: yes
    Trusted: yes
    Blocked: no
    Connected: yes
    LegacyPairing: no
    UUID: Headset                   (00001108-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Audio Sink                (0000110b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: A/V Remote Control Target (0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: A/V Remote Control        (0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Handsfree                 (0000111e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: PnP Information           (00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Generic Access Profile    (00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Generic Attribute Profile (00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Device Information        (0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Battery Service           (0000180f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Unknown                   (0000fdce-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Vendor specific           (a2129ff3-081b-4c45-8afe-469d9c4842eb)
    Modalias: bluetooth:v000Ap0160dFFFF
```

But as per syslog it shows device registered as keyboard

```
Apr 20 11:08:35 doit /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2423]: (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "HD 350BT (AVRCP)" (type: KEYBOARD, id 23)
Apr 20 11:08:35 doit /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2423]: (II) event21 - HD 350BT (AVRCP): is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
Apr 20 11:08:35 doit /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2423]: (II) event21 - HD 350BT (AVRCP): device is a keyboard
```

From the bluetooth device info class its well defined as a headset class. Is the syslog written info a bug or an issue?

Answer (score 0):

The device probably has some buttons, so `xinput` may use them as "keys". I see no problems of the headset works well.

And the title of the question is not correct. Adding a `xinput` new device doesn't mean "a wrong device name".

Comment: thanks for those..i meant "type: KEYBOARD"

Comment: Xinput has types: keyboard, mouse, etc.